# mysqli and global variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been been on this for hours trying to find the small mistake I've done and I just can't find it... All I'm doing is calling a variable as global in a function and it's just not working even though it worked fine with the function above it...

I get an error saying mysqli is null...

```
include 'data/mysqli_connect.php'; 

function process_login(){

global $mysqli;

$username = $_SESSION['username'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM auth WHERE user='".mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$username)."'";
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);


if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){

$sql = "DELETE FROM auth WHERE user='".mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$username)."'";
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);


if(!$query){

die(mysqli_error());

}

}


$sql = "INSERT INTO auth (user, session) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$username)."', '".$_SESSION['id']."')";
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

if(!$query){

echo "Can not insert info into database!<br />". mysqli_error();

}else{

header("Location:chat.php");

}

}


function logout(){

global $mysqli;

$sql = "DELETE FROM auth WHERE session='".mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_SESSION['id']). "'";
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);


if(!$query){

echo "Can not delete info from database!";

}else{

session_destroy();
header("Location: chat.php");

}

}


function get_username(){

global $mysqli;


$sql = "SELECT * FROM auth WHERE session='".mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_SESSION['id']). "'";
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);


if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == "0"){

$username = "Guest";

}else{

$username = $row['user'];

 }

 return $username;

}



function post_message(){

global $mysqli;

$text = addslashes(htmlentities(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['text'])));


$sql = "INSERT INTO chat (time, user, text) VALUES ('".date("H:i")."', '".get_username()."', '".$text."')";

$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);


if(!$query){

die(mysqli_error());

}

}

    mysqli_connect.php
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect(localhost, "info", "info", "info");
```

Like I said it worked on the function above this one but not this one, it doesn't make sens... I'm guessing I have a stupid mistake in there somewhere just don't know where.

By the way,the functions that I tested and work are `process_login()` and `logout()` and `get_username()`

`get_username()` runs first then `process_login()`. `post_message()` runs from a jquery code that calls it when i press on enter that probably works fine since i can see the error code when i press enter.

Oh and sorry about the bad code formatting,not sure how to fix it on here.

Thank you for any help or advice you may find.

Comment: Start learning about prepared statements. What you call *"Let's clean our text that user entered"* in a comment is totally wrong.

Comment: Oh forgot to say I get the error that $mysqli is null so empty and I've tested it, really is empty...

Comment: I would first suggest putting `localhost` as `'localhost'`

Comment: Regarding @Jon 's comment - PHP's misfeature of treating unknown constants as strings with E_NOTICE makes the `localhost` work as is.  Turn on `display_errors` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to see how PHP is handling that constant..

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski They're already on, they don't give anything ... the only error I guess is that $mysqli is null. Well it says  "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null"  but yeah that it...

Comment: Was it defined in global scope? Or did you `include` the connection script within somewhere else?

Comment: @mario well basically it's an `include` inside of an `include` but that shouldn't really matter because it was in a global scope.Both `includes` follow one another and they're not in a function to add to it the weird thing is that `$mysqli` is defined with a function that's above `post_message()`. So I really don't get why it's not working.

Comment: Can you show us the entire code (including the previous function) and the order that they run so we can help figure out why it is undefined for `post_message()`?

Comment: @Jon sure but it's pretty long, I'll edit my main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How/When is `post_message()` called?  From what you edited in, I can't find anything specifically in that that would clear the `$mysqli` variable - but to debug it, we would need more of the program flow.

Or you could create a 'hack' in the code and within `post_message()` after you declare `global $mysqli;`, do `include 'data/mysqli_connect.php';` again since the `$mysqli` reference to your DB connection has been lost by then.  But, ideally, you need to follow the flow of your code to figure out where to fix it correctly - and your flow seems not to be able to be posted fully, or is too great to post fully here.

(Too long for a comment, so this response comes in answer form, my apologies.)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, after reviewing the flow several times I realized that i had mistaken the directory when sending the file in jquery, sorry for the trouble...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making $mysqli a global variable, try passing it as an additional parameter to your functions. I was having the same problem and that's how i solved it. ie...

```
function post_message($mysqli){


$text = addslashes(htmlentities(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['text'])));


$sql = "INSERT INTO chat (time, user, text) VALUES ('".date("H:i")."', 
'".get_username()."', '".$text."')";

$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);


if(!$query){

die(mysqli_error());

}
```

Hope this works for you.